# fdisk shows partitions type Linux and dos on the same partitions

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fdisk, partition-table

I have created a partition on my disk like this:

```
root@vps-90446fc7:~# fdisk /dev/sdb

Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.37.2).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.


Command (m for help): n
Partition type
   p   primary (0 primary, 0 extended, 4 free)
   e   extended (container for logical partitions)
Select (default p): 

Using default response p.
Partition number (1-4, default 1): 
First sector (2048-419430399, default 2048): 
Last sector, +/-sectors or +/-size{K,M,G,T,P} (2048-419430399, default 419430399): 

Created a new partition 1 of type 'Linux' and of size 200 GiB.

Command (m for help): w
The partition table has been altered.
Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table.
Syncing disks.
```

Then I check the created partition:

```
root@vps-90446fc7:~# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sdb: 200 GiB, 214748364800 bytes, 419430400 sectors
Disk model: QEMU HARDDISK   
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xfef6f988

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1        2048 419430399 419428352  200G 83 Linux
```

I says: `Disklabel type: dos` which is already weird.

`parted` says is MSDOS partition:

```
root@vps-90446fc7:~# parted -l
Model: QEMU QEMU HARDDISK (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 215GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size   Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  215GB  215GB  primary
```

`e2fsck` doesn't recognize the partition:

```
e2fsck -f /dev/sdb1
e2fsck 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
e2fsck: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
e2fsck: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdb1

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>

Found a dos partition table in /dev/sdb1
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong. I just want to create a normal Linux (whatever type is good) partition to store files.

Comment: For over 10 years gpt has been preferred, but many tools still default to MBR(msdos). GPT Advantages (older 2010 but still valid)  see post#2 by srs5694:
[gpt Advantages](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1457901) & 
https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Partitioning#Choosing_between_GPT_and_MBR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've created an MBR partition table (also known as a DOS partition table) on the device `/dev/sdb`. It contains one entry that's labelled as a Linux partition, `/dev/sdb1`. The "Linux" label is purely informational and does not enable or restrict any features.

You now need to create a filesystem on that partition, for example like this:

```
mkfs.ext4 -L data /dev/sdb1
```

And then you can mount it into your system. For example, this will mount it at `/mnt/dsk`:

```
mkdir -p /mnt/dsk
mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/dsk
```

Provided you remember to unmount the filesystem (`umount /mnt/dsk`) before removing it, you should never need to use `e2fsck`. The system will automatically unmount all filesystems when it's cleanly shut down, so you don't need to remember to do it then yourself.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your partition. DOS/MSDOS partition table ([MBR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record)) is standard partition table which is used both in Windows and Linux. Newer GPT ([GUID Partition Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table)) is nowadays usually preferred, but there is nothing wrong with using MSDOS partition table.

`e2fsck` doesn't recognize your partition because you haven't created the ext4 filesystem on your new partition yet. Partition is just a block device, you need to format it first. If you want to use Ext, run `mke2fs /dev/sdb1` after creating the partition with `fdisk` or `parted`.